# How to get instagram number of followers using instaload?

Tags: python, instagram

I am using instaload librabry

source code is [here](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/blob/master/instaloader/structures.py)

```
 # Get instance
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(username, password)        # (login)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "pink_sfsu")

# Print list of followees
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    print(followee)
```

I am trying to retrieve the number of followers of the followers of the account. I successfully get the follower of the account but can manage to know its number of follower. I am reading the source code. Because I assume that instaloader already do similar things to get all the followers of a page. Therefore I try to extend this but don't succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
# Print all followers with their followers count
for follower in profile.get_followers():
    print('{} has {} followers'.format(follower.username, follower.followers))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the followers of your followers, according to the documentation, this should do it.

```
followers_of_followers = []
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    followers_of_followers.extend(followee.get_followers())
```

Comment: yes but that is costly process as it gets all the followers information I just want the count.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the number of followers

```
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(username, password)        # (login)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "pink_sfsu")
followers = profile.get_followers()
number_of_followers = followers.count
print(number_of_followers)
```